# Manipulating JSON data during Deserialization into class model

Tags: c#, json

Is it possible to add two JSON fields together when deserializing?

For example:

```
public class root{
    public List<cars> carList{get;set;}
}

public class cars{
    public int HondaValue{get;set;}
    public int fordValue{get;set;}
    public int totalValue{get;set;}
}
```

JSON :

```
{
  "carList":
    {
     "hondaValue":30,000,
     "fordValue":40,000,
    },
    {
     "hondaValue":55,000,
     "fordValue":62,000,
    },
    {
     "hondaValue":77,000,
     "fordValue":65,000,
    },
}
```

So can I get the sum of the hondaValue and fordValue for the total value in my class model during deserialization? Or do I have to set them to my model values after deserialization and add/set them to total?

Comment: Is this valid int `30,000`?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean when you say "add the values together", do you mean store the sum in totalValue? if so then yes, you'd probably need to iterate over the list before serializing.

Comment: This string isn't valid JSON. It contains multiple errors. Commas in the values, the second dictionary entry has no key. `carList` is actually a dictionary/object, not a list

Comment: There are some miss match between the object property and the Json name you can use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FooBar")]` to have a more consitent naming.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Json or deserialisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do a foreach just do it like this:

```cs
public struct Cars
{    
   public int HondaValue { get; set; }    
   public int FordValue { get; set; }
   public int TotalValue 
   { 
      get 
      {
         return HondaValue + FordValue;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you but what if I wanted maybe to subtract,divide and multiply them by 100? would I write all the code in the get{...}? or can I call a method perhaps?

Comment: You can write a method or the code in the get, it boils down to the same thing